# how many miners should you run on one graphic card?

Tags: mining

I currently run one. should I run more? if no, why? if yes, how do I do it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graphics card has a certain mining capacity it can provide. So deciding how many miners to use is not really relevent as the capacity will just be split between the number of miners.

> Here is an example:
>
> Let's say your GPU produces 100MH/s. If you use one miner, that miner
> will produce rewards based on the 100MH/S capacity. If you split your
> GPU between 2 miners, each will provide rewards based on 50MH/S.

So, it does not really matter.
I hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your kind reply :) I really appreciate the simplicity and clarity